# Jena API differenciate between class and instance of a class

Tags: class, rdf, jena, ontology

When using Jena API to list all the statements conforming a resource, I don't find a way to differentiate if either subject or object are instances of a class or a class itself.

```
<http://jlanza.net/node1>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#Device>
<http://jlanza.net/node1>  <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#onPlatform>  <<http://jlanza.net/node2>
```

`node1` and `node2` is what I call an instance or individual, while the `http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#Device` is the class it instantiate.

Do you know of any way of differentiating it? By using `isUriResource()`, `isResource()`, etc. I get the same result. Let's also say that it is not just valid to get the `rdf:type` property as there might be other properties that link to a class.

Any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In general, there's not much difference

RDF, by itself, doesn't make this distinction.  **Rdf:type** is just another IRI that is commonly used as a property.  In practice, of course, we assign some special meanings to **rdf:type** whereby we indicate class membership.  That is, when we have a triple of the form

```
x rdf:type y
```

we say that (the individual) x is an instance of (the class) y.  But in RDF(S) inference, this also lets us infer that

```
y rdf:type rdfs:Class
```

which means that (the individual, but also a class) y is an instance of (the class) **rdfs:Class**.  So there's no real clear distinction between individuals and classes.  In fact, for a property p, we also have that

```
p rdf:type rdfs:Property
```

so (the property) p is *also* an individual!  In pure RDF, the only way to determine "the type" of an individual is to look for the its **rdf:type** values.  And the only way to determine whether something is a class is to look for either:

- it being used as a class, i.e., as the object in a triple of the form **x rdf:type C**; or
- is being declared as a class with a triple like **C rdf:type rdfs:Class** (or, if you're using OWL, **C rdf:type owl:Class**).

### In Jena, OntResource can check with isClass and isIndividual

In Jena, though, if you use an **OntModel** and get resource as an instance of [**OntResouce**](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntResource.html), you can use the methods [**isClass()**](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#isClass--) and [**isIndividual()**](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#isIndividual--) to check whether a resource can be viewed as a class or an individual.  Note that those method descriptions include (emphasis added):

> Answer true if this resource **can be viewed** as a class

> Answer true if this resource **can be viewed** as an individual

That phrase, "can be viewed" is important, because as I described above, resources can be classes, individuals, and properties, all at the same time.  It might be possible for a resource to be viewed as more than one thing.  But these methods will probably work for most use cases.